# Authentication problem with the botframework

Tags: microsoft-teams

In order to submit our application, we also need to use the bot, we will need your help as we failed at the authentication. We followed the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#step-1-request-an-access-token-from-the-msaaad-v2-login-service

We guess it is related to permission issues because once we try to generate a token and want to use the generated token, the problem occurs.

```
Header:
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization: Bearer <<token>>

Body:
{
   "type":"MESSAGE",
   "id":"1562671711817",
   "serviceUrl":"https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/",
   "channelId":"msteams",
   "recipient":{
      "id":"29:1c1YrZz-Y8s4rqz6kv-6IQEitST-4c4WXahJm75Q8vFgc6VW2-zSZ4bRSuXB1UnGslpgsgqsZaTotdReThcP0MA",
      "name":"Bence Murányi"
   },
   "conversation":{
      "conversationType":"personal",
      "id":"a:1loTp40Q75PM0dPSzjV7cf0hD6Y1ojqX1EUX-dvInosr8blihhsUUJeUbP0VDdTsThEq8BLZVQAhr01eOSwfvc3g_BhdqtYkPrpu_NtIjicyc0eAOMUvfFlIhwzklNHFe"
   },
   "from":{
      "id":"28:b6e3791c-e6d6-4dac-bd30-d2c98f853a8a",
      "name":"test bot2"
   },
   "textFormat":"PLAIN",
   "locale":"en-US",
   "text":"dssdasa",
   "entities":[
      {
         "type":"clientInfo"
      }
   ],
   "channelData":{
      "tenant":{
         "id":"f40d28f0-fa73-4100-bdad-85e72b983110"
      }
   }
}

Response:
Status code: 401 Unauthorized
Body:
{
    "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go to manifest and change the signInAudience to **AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount**.
Please have a look at signInAudience in [Manifest reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#manifest-reference).

[image]

Comment: We have the same, https://imgur.com/oDG7qqU, the problem should be something different.